# singleThreaded parameter in testng not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to check a small code with Threads in selenium TestNG.

Here is my code:

```
@Test(singleThreaded=false)
public class testngannotations {

    @Test
    public void t1(){
        System.out.print("t1");
        System.out.println("thread 1: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    @Test
    public void t3(){
        System.out.print("t3");
        System.out.println("thread 3: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
}
```

When I run the code I can see just one thread running. Anything I am doing wrong here? Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations):

> singleThreaded: If set to true, all the methods on this test class are guaranteed to run in the same thread, even if the tests are currently being run with parallel="methods". This attribute can only be used at the class level and it will be ignored if used at the method level. Note: this attribute used to be called sequential (now deprecated).

In other words, you have to choose a `parallel` strategy if you want to have parallel runs of your tests.